# SQL Report Builder Expressions - How do I display value on report as "---" if the data value field does not any data

Tags: sql-server, expression, reportbuilder

I have tried using the following expression but receive an error message

```
IIF(First(Fields!EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value, "ConsumerIndex") = True, First(Fields!EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value, "ConsumerIndex"), "---")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it-

=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value), "---", Fields!EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work I used the expression =IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value), "---", EmploymentDetailsOccupation.Value), "ConsumerIndex") but received the message The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox42’ refers directly to the field ‘EmploymentDetailsOccupation’ without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.